# Why am I getting a popup message when I hover on any word of a Ruby file?

Tags: ruby, vim, editor

If I hover the mouse on any word of a Ruby file, I get a tooltip message.

A screenshot of that popup message is at [popup message](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/screenshotji.png/).

`cat ~/.gvimrc` returns:

```
function! SyntaxBalloon()
    let synID   = synID(v:beval_lnum, v:beval_col, 0)
    let groupID = synIDtrans(synID)
    let name    = synIDattr(synID, "name")
    let group   = synIDattr(groupID, "name")
    return name . "\n" . group
endfunction

set balloonexpr=SyntaxBalloon()
set ballooneval

"how syntax highlighting groups for word under cursor
nmap <F2> :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>
function! <SID>SynStack()
    if !exists("*synstack")
        return
    endif
    echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're are using vim-ruby I guess. Well, this plugin defined a [balloonexpr](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27balloonexpr%27). You can read it [here](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/ftplugin/ruby.vim#L184). Personally I find it quite annoying so I have disabled it with:

```
setlocal balloonexpr=
```

in my `.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim` file.

Comment: No, it's NERD_tree.vim in ~/.vim/plugin, i updated the original post/question. See that again to understand.

Answer (score 24):

The cleanest simplest way is to put this in your .vimrc:

- `:set noballooneval`

Place it after you initialize Syntastic and Pathogen, if you use those plugins.

In some instances people have had problems with setting noballooneval, there's a few work-arounds:

- If something is overwriting your noballooneval setting you can use `:verb set ballooneval?` to watch changes to it.
- `:set balloondelay=100000`
- `:setlocal balloonexpr=`
- Find the offending line in the plugin you're using and comment it out (grep for `balloon`).
- If you are building your own Vim, `balloon_eval` is a compile-time configuration option, you can use that to enable or disable the feature.

References:

- https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/ruby.vim#L62
- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/debugger.html#balloon-eval
- http://icy.io/osx/macvim-ruby-balloon-issue

See also: [I get this window while editing Ruby Files in Vim. What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871465/i-get-this-window-while-editing-ruby-files-in-vim-what-is-it)

Comment: If anyone else is using Eclim, you can disable the popup adding `let g:EclimShowCurrentErrorBalloon = 0` to your .vimrc

Answer (score 5):

If you're using MacVim, the built-in netrw plugin will overwrite your `set noballooneval` setting. You have to do this:

```
" Disable hover tooltips
set noballooneval
let g:netrw_nobeval = 1
```

Comment: This answer deserves a higher score, since in my case it *was* netrw clobbering my settings. Notably, this was in gVim on Linux so it's not just MacVim. Also, the suggestion of `:verb set ballooneval?` didn't catch this for some reason. And the clobbering stuck around after I finished using netrw. The typical way I'd trigger the bug was:

1. Start using Vim (`noballooneval` is set)
2. Open and navigate a directory, activating netrw (it clobbers with `ballooneval`).
3. Open a Ruby file in that buffer. Later, get assaulted with a popup (`ballooneval` is still active)

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the tooltip is the default output of `ri` when run without arguments.

I think I saw an almost identical problem here a few weeks ago: a `ri` vim script/macro that somehow didn't send the correct argument (word under cursor) to `ri`.

You should hunt down the script/plugin/macro/autocommand that is supposed to interact with `ri` and see if:

1. It effectively grabs the word under cursor.
2. Actually sends it to `ri`.
3. Uses the right API to talk to `ri`.

Do you use Janus or some other "distro"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, netrw's balloon help only shows up when the cursor is in a netrw buffer and in netrw's banner.  In particular, it does not affect ruby files.